# Permutation of a sum - generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> How many ways can we combine $1, 2$ and $5$ dollars into a vending machine, in a total sum of $n$ - no need to get a closed form expression, just show the generating function. differentiate between ordered and unordered cases. (Without using exponential generating function)

**My Attempt -**

So the unordered case feels kind of obvious - I define $x_1 = 1+x+x^2+..., x_2 = 1+x^2+x^4+...,x_5=1+x^5+x^{10}+...$
, $x_1 + x_2 + x_5 = n$. And the generating function as such - $f(x) = \lambda x\in \Bbb{R}. \dfrac{1}{1-x} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x^5}$.

The second case is a little bit more confusing, i thought about something like -

$f(x) = \lambda x\in\Bbb{R}.\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(1+x+x^2+x^5)^i$

I really am not sure this is a good generating function for that case, any thoughts ?

Comment: don't catch the meaning of "order" in this problem

Comment: Let's say that in $n=8$, i want to count every $(5,2,1), (2,1,5), (1,2,5)...$ and not only $(1,2,5), (2,2,2,2), (1,1,1,...1)...$.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. So .. that is a strange (or highly evoluted) machine, one in which you can exchange the position of the $3$ coin-depots.

Comment: Hint: If you used exactly two 1/2/5 dollar bills, then $(x+x^2+x^5)(x+x^2+x^5)$ would give you... what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting unordered cases you can use recursive function $F(n;5,2,1)$ wich gives number of combines 1,2 and 5 dollars for represent $n$ dollars. For $n=8$:

$F(8;5,2,1)=F(3;2,1)+F(8;2,1)=F(1;1)+F(3;1)+F(6;2,1)+F(8;1)=1+1+F(4;2,1)+F(6;1)+1=
2+F(2;2,1)+F(4;1)+2=2+F(2;2,1)+F(4;1)+2=2+2+1+2=7$.